# How to Angular unit test case for Subscribe for jasmine-karma?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write test cases for array of subscription, when I tried to subscribe the getUserData method in the user service, it is giving me maximum call stack error.

It is not allowing me to call & subscribe to the data. can anyone please help me to write test cases for subscription.push.

user.component.ts:

```
         import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
         import {UserService} from "../services/user.service";
         import { Subscription} from "rxjs";

       @Component({
                 selector: 'user',
                 templateUrl: './user.component.html',
                styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
         })

        export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

          user;
          subscription:Subscription[]=[];

          constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

          getData(){
             this.subscription.push(
                 this.userService.getUserData().subscribe({
                         next: (data) => {
                              if (data.status === 'SUCCESS') {
                                     this.user= data.user;
                              }
                          },
                         error: (error) => {
                                    console.log(error);
                         },
                  })
               );
            }
        }
```

user.component.spec.ts

```
          import {UserComponent} from './user.component';
          import {async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
          import {of} from 'rxjs';
          import {UserService} from "../services/user.service";
         
          describe('UserComponent', () => {
              it(`should call getData method`,fakeAsync(()=>{
              const spyOnData =  spyOn(component.userService,'getUserData').and.returnValue(of(mockUserData));
              component.getData();
              tick();
              expect(spyOnData ).toHaveBeenCalled();
              }));
          }
```

Comment: `this.subscritpion` is not an `Array`. Why are you `push`ing on it?

Comment: this.subscription is array only, i have updated the code.

Comment: So where is the stacktrace? I dont see any potential stackoverflow issues here.